# Why does running a single threaded Java program result in many cores active?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, jvm, benchmarking

I was benchmarking the total delay casting to datatype from `Object` will have. But I encountered a very weird behavior of a Java collection, in this case, a `List`.

```
List<Long> data = new ArrayList<>();
int SIZE = 50_000_000;

long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    data.add(currentTime++);
}
```

When running the above code the CPU Utilization on my **Intel i5 8250u** (4 cores) the CPU utilization was 100% running on IntelliJ Idea. So I thought it could be because of IntelliJ, hence I move the code to Azure VM (running CentOS 7.4) having 20 Cores and to my surprise, this piece of code ended consuming **1500%** CPU (result from `top` command) which is 15 cores.

What I'm not able to understand is this: How can a single-threaded Java program code consume more than 1 core?

> EDIT:

**Steps to Reproduce:**

Run the above code.

**Machine Configuration:**

Laptop: 4 Cores 16Gb RAM, Oracle Java 1.8_161

Azure VM: 20 Cores 148GB RAM, Oracle Java 1.8_161

**Output From JVisualVM on Laptop:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Because the JVM itself has some work to do outside of your actual Java code (including garbage collection and JIT-compiling hot loops), but some of that overhead can be parallelized.  Possibly even parallelizing the memcpy when the ArrayList has to reallocate.

Comment: But 1500% is a lot considering the simplicity of the code.

Comment: Yeah, 15 cores is more thread-level parallelism that I'd have expected, might be interesting to profile the JVM and see where it's spending all that CPU time.  (e.g. with `perf record` / `perf report`).  The JVM itself is ahead-of-time compiled and relatively simple for profiling tools to handle, except for its blocks of JIT-compiled guest code.

Comment: I think maybe you got the downvotes because it asks a complicated question but it doesn't have enough details to really investigate the problem. You'd have to describe more about how the measurements are done, recordings of the measurements, and the commands that can be used to reproduce them.

Comment: What JVM are you using on the CentOS system?  Is it different from your desktop?

Comment: @Lii: It does say it's measured using `top`, which does accurately show CPU utilization per process.  Only thing missing is how long that 1500% is sustained for, but otherwise that's most of the way to sufficient for measurement.  (Although `time java foo.jar` or whatever would show overall user / system time as well as wall-clock and thus average threads running).  IMO the missing details are mostly in JVM version / options.

Comment: Added More Details

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your test does nothing but allocating memory. So it quickly exhausts initial heap memory, causing Full GC to run. The heap then increases, but it gets filled quickly again, causing another Full GC, etc.

```
$ java -XX:+PrintGC Test
[GC (Allocation Failure)  27648K->20757K(104448K), 0.0296779 secs]
[GC (Allocation Failure)  48405K->40538K(132096K), 0.0293287 secs]
[GC (Allocation Failure)  83084K->82453K(138752K), 0.0615143 secs]
[Full GC (Ergonomics)  82453K->75113K(225792K), 0.5392036 secs]
[GC (Allocation Failure)  124981K->139346K(254464K), 0.0563272 secs]
[Full GC (Ergonomics)  139346K->112504K(353792K), 0.5240216 secs]
[GC (Allocation Failure)  185709K->208841K(380416K), 0.0864858 secs]
[Full GC (Ergonomics)  208841K->168513K(512512K), 0.9035611 secs]
...
```

So, what you observe is a series of long Full GC cycles. The default garbage collector in JDK 8 is Parallel, with the number of parallel GC threads equal to the number of CPUs.

If you run [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/) in threaded mode (`-t`), you'll find that almost all CPU time is spent running garbage collection in multiple threads.

[image: CPU profile]

Comment: Wow. I'm amazed. Thank you so much. I tried giving a bigger Initial heap memory and this behaviour is not seen.